# Sorting a Realm Results object in the background thread

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to sort a Realm Results instance in a background thread. But I am getting '**Realm accessed from incorrect thread.**' exception. What am I doing wrong here?.

**I'm using this function to filter and update the table with the result as the text in the search bar text field changes.**

Thanks in advance.

```
var previousSearchWork?

func getInvoicesFor(searchedTerm: String, completion: @escaping ([Invoice]) -> Void) {
        previousSearchWork?.cancel()
        
        let newSearchWork = DispatchWorkItem {
            guard let realm = try? Realm() else { return }
            
            var filteredInvoices = [Invoice]()
            if searchedTerm.first!.isLetter { // searching by customer name
                
                let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@ || name CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchedTerm, searchedTerm)
                let invoices = realm.objects(Invoice.self).filter(predicate)
                filteredInvoices = invoices.sorted {
                    $0.name!.levenshteinDistance(searchedTerm) < $1.name!.levenshteinDistance(searchedTerm)
                }
                
            } else {  // searching by id
                // ...
            }
            completion(filteredInvoices)
        }
        previousSearchWork = newSearchWork
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(30), execute: newSearchWork)
    }
```

Comment: @West1 I am intentionally running newSearchWork on a background thread cause the function doing some time consuming tasks. I do not want my ui to become unresponsive every time I call the function. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Any time a Swift filter is applied on objc Realm objects, those objects 'disconnect' from Realm and are no longer live-updating Realm objects. So this `.sorted { $0.name!` is probably causing the issue. Sort the invoices using a Realm sort, not swift. Also, it appears you're searching strings for whatever the user typed; CONTAINS searches the entire string, including the first part of the string and BEGINSWITH also searches the first part of the string. Do you need both? Also, that Realm is on a background thread so the objects are on that thread; what happens with `[Invoice]` upon completion?

Comment: @Jay "Realm is on a background thread so the objects are on that thread; what happens with [Invoice] upon completion?"

That's what caused the exception. I tried to read them on the main thread even though I fetched them in a background thread. I've already solved this issue. Thank you so much btw.

Comment: @Jay. I can't use realm sorts because they do not suffice to my need. For instance I am sorting by comparing their levenshteinDistance to searched string.

Comment: Understood. However, the important part is sorting them using Swift disconnects them from Realm and they will not longer be able to be used in notifications and will not be live updating Realm objects. Glad you resolved the issue. perhaps you can post the coding solution to help future readers.

Comment: In my situation, the there's no chance of any modifications happening to any of realm objects while there’s a calling to this function so It didn't mattered to me here but I'm gonna give it a try. My current solution to the problem probably a really poor one. I'll post it anyway. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jay has mentioned in a reply to the original question:

> ...  that Realm is on a background thread so the objects are on that thread; what happens with [Invoice] upon completion?

Yep, it turns out I've been fetching Realm persisted objects on a **background thread** and send it to the caller via completion closure and then the caller tries to read them on **main thread**. That's what triggered the '**Realm accessed from incorrect thread**'

First of all, I couldn't find a way to sort the objects without transforming it to an array of realm objects since I needed to use a custom sorting method.

All I did to fix the above function was instead of returning an array of Objects that are fetched inside a background thread, I am returning references to those objects so I can refer to them in main thread

According to my poor research, I've found two ways to pass those objects from background thread to main thread. *(I went for the second way cause as to what've read, it's faster for this case.*)

```
let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global()
let mainThread = DispatchQueue.main
    
    // Passing as ThreadSafeReferences to objects
    backgroundQueue.async {
        let bgRealm = try! Realm()
        let myObjects = bgRealm.objects(MyObject.self)
        // ......
        let myObjectsArray = .....
        let references: [ThreadSafeReference<MyObject>] = myObjectsArray.map { ThreadSafeReference(to: $0) }
        
        mainThread.async {
            let mainRealm = try! Realm()
            let myObjectsArray: [MyObject?] = references.map { mainRealm.resolve($0) }
        }
    }
    
    // Passing primaryKeys of objects
    backgroundQueue.async {
        let bgRealm = try! Realm()
        let myObjects = bgRealm.objects(MyObject.self)
        // ......
        let myObjectsArray = .....
        // MyObject has a property called 'id' which is the primary key
        let keys: [String] = itemsArray.map { $0.id }
        
        mainThread.async {
            let mainRealm = try! Realm()
            let myObjectsArray: [MyObject?] = keys.map { mainRealm.object(ofType: MyObject.self, forPrimaryKey: $0) }
        }
    }
```

After adjusting the function (and completing it for my need):

```
var previousSearchWork: DispatchWorkItem?
func getInvoicesFor(searchedTerm: String, completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
        previousSearchWork?.cancel()
        
        let newSearchWork = DispatchWorkItem {
            autoreleasepool {
                var filteredIDs = [String]()
                
                guard let realm = try? Realm() else { return }
                let allInvoices = realm.objects(Invoice.self).filter(NSPredicate(format: "dateDeleted == nil"))
                
                if searchedTerm.first!.isLetter {
                    
                    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@ || name CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchedTerm, searchedTerm)
                    let invoices = allInvoices.filter(predicate)
                    filteredIDs = invoices.sorted {
                        $0.name!.levenshtein(searchedTerm) < $1.name!.levenshtein(searchedTerm)
                    }.map {$0.id}
                    
                } else {
                    var predicates = [NSPredicate(format: "%@ IN ticket.pattern.sequences", searchedTerm)]
                    
                    if searchedTerm.count > 3 {
                        let regex = searchedTerm.charactersSorted().reduce("*") {$0 + "\($1)*"}
                        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ticket.pattern.id LIKE %@", regex)
                        predicates.append(predicate)
                    }
                    
                    let invoices = allInvoices.filter(NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)).sorted(byKeyPath: "dateCreated", ascending: false)
                    filteredIDs = Array(invoices.map {$0.id})
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(filteredIDs)
                }
            }
        }
        previousSearchWork = newSearchWork
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(30), execute: newSearchWork)
    }
```